# video in html5 - movie not found in firefox

Tags: html, video

I have a following code, which should show a video from file **139multiclub_mix.mp4**. This file is in the same folder as file with html code. In browser Chrome all works fine. But in Firefox i see a default movie (from http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv) but my movie isn't shown. What i'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" width="274" height="206" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" preload="auto">
<source src="139multiclub_mix.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;" />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" />
<object id="sampleMovie" width="274" height="206" data="../../../../plugins/forms/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="src" value="../../../../plugins/forms/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="url=139multiclub_mix.mp4&amp;poster=/admin/box/edit-box/id/" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="true" /></object> </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Firefox still don't support MP4. Add ogv file for Firefox.

See: [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#Browser_compatibility)

> To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not
>   built directly into Firefox.

Comment: Ok. so i converted this file to .ogv format and i putted in this code. Thanks for help!